# Batch node operations in Drupal 5

Tags: drupal

What is the most efficient way to go through and update every single node in a drupal site, to, for instance mechanically add tags? Drupal 6 has a shiny new batch API, but what to do in Drupal 5?

I started writing a script that keeps a pointer and then goes around all nodes on a cron, loads them and then saves them, but I wonder what else could be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't suggest working directly on the database level since some modules might want to update some other related tables. The most reliable and flexible way is to write a script to load, change and save nodes in a loop. You can also try using additional special modules for Drupal 5:

- [Taxonomy Node Operations](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_node_operations)
- [Taxonomy Multi Editor](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_multi_edit) (similar functionality)
- and more general module [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Job queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_queue) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... used by modules to queue function calls for execution on cron. The job_queue_add() function is used by modules to add a job to the queue
>
> This module is end of life for Drupal 7, there is a [queue in core](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.queue.inc/7/source).

Answer (score 0):

hmm i'm not familiar with drupal 5's database structure, but if it's similar enough to drupal 6, you could just modify this all pretty easily by just working off the `term_node` table. it's a mapper of node id's to term id's:

```
term_node
- nid
- vid
- tid
```

nid is the node id of course, vid is the revision id, if you use revisions, and tid is the term id. terms are all stored in `term_data`

```
term_data
- tid
- name
```

are the more interesting columns. so if you already have existing terms, you can create a quick map of existing tid's, then add to whatever nodes you want in term_node. anyhow, being careless in this regard could possibly cause weird data issues, so i wouldn't suggest this approach unless you feel pretty comfortable with the raw database.

Comment: doing things on the db level is not something that I want to do - there is a lot more risk to mess everything up in a subtle way and then not notice until it's too late.